# Graphing real-time data from a text file

Tags: data-visualization, real-time

I have a process which writes statistics from a server system to a file each second in this format:

```
label1 label2 label3
344 666 787
344 849 344
939 994 344
```

There are a number of different values which I need graphs for, and each value is added to the bottom of the file each second.

I am looking for a nice way to show these numbers graphically, preferably a program which auto-updates each second and shows the different graphs.

Can anyone recommend such a program for mac? Preferably a free one :)

Answer (score 7):

I had really good luck with the KDE program [kst](http://kst.kde.org):

> Kst is the fastest real-time large-dataset viewing and plotting tool available
>   and has basic data analysis functionality.
>   Kst contains many powerful built-in features and is expandable with plugins
>   and extensions. Extensive help is available, both from within Kst and on the
>   web.
>   Kst is licenced under the GPL and is freely available for anyone.

It can handle much higher update frequency than once a second. It also happens to be file-based, but I don't know how much work it is to get this going on OS X.

On Ubuntu and Debian, `sudo apt-get install kst` is all it takes.

Answer (score 2):

RRDTool looks like it might be exactly what you are looking for. I've never tried to run it on a Mac but it looks like someone has some info on that here: http://rrdtool.darwinports.com/

Good luck!

Comment: RRDTool can be found here: http://www.mrtg.org/rrdtool/index.en.html